# How to get first row from Google Spreadsheets Data API

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-data-api

Here is an example: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1a2JzZzUjSIcpROgR5v_M-UmWyT-iokcegIxHJOopZWA/od6/public/full?alt=json

The returned JSON data doesn't contain the first row from the spreadsheet.
You can view the contents of the spreadsheet in HTML (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a2JzZzUjSIcpROgR5v_M-UmWyT-iokcegIxHJOopZWA/pubhtml) to verify that "first row" exists in the sheet.

How can I get the first row from the spreadsheet? There is a "openSearch$startIndex" = 1 in the returned JSON. Maybe if you could set this to 0, I could get the first row also.

Comment: Are you using a list-based feed? In particular, the list feed treats the first row of the worksheet as a header row; Spreadsheets dynamically creates XML elements named after the contents of header-row cells. However, have you had a chance to take a look at [this](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation! Python is not an option in my case, but I can live without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Row - Cell feed

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/key/worksheetId/private/full?min-row=1&min-col=1&max-col=4

**Docs:** https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#fetching_specific_rows_or_columns

Cell feed is better for almost everything. But append a data row is better in list feed, I think.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you would do it like this:

```cs
var link = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.CellRel, null).HRef.ToString();
var cellQuery = new CellQuery(link)
    {
        MinimumRow = 1,
        MaximumRow = 1,
        MinimumColumn = 1
    };
CellFeed header = spreadsheetService.Query(cellQuery);
```